# Setting to protect gnome-terminal from key logging

Tags: xorg, security

Looks like it is easy to log keystrokes of all processes of the same user. A basic keylogger is 'xinput'.

```
xinput test-xi2
```

The command generates log of all key-presses. Unfortunately, this includes passwords in gnome-terminal. Googling suggested that grabbing keyboard may prevent other windows from capturing key strokes.

Is there a way to prevent XI2 logging in gnome-terminal? Or is there an X terminal that has this feature?

Comment: Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247452/how-to-restrict-a-user-from-accessing-a-particular-application) a solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible as *any* keystrokes passed on to the X server, will be available for xinput/any arbitrary program. (In fact, it's part of the design). New display servers like Wayland and Mir are fixing such security problems in X. The only real solution would be to use Wayland or Mir instead of X. [This](http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.in/2011/04/linux-security-circus-on-gui-isolation.html) blog post details this issue.

Comment: So input to gksu for password also goes to xinput?

Comment: @yanychar yup, actually I found out about this method of key logging through this blog post: http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.in/2011/04/linux-security-circus-on-gui-isolation.html (even I was surprised the first time I read the blog post)

Comment: X11 actually has untrusted mode which you can use to prevent programs from accessing "bad" extensions - https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Security/

Comment: I found out this is incorrect: i3lock-color somehow prevents sniffing the password that is being typed via xi2.

Answer (score -2):

Not really. Even if you somehow manage to grab the keyboard within X (I don't know whether this is even possible, I doubt that), a keylogger utility running as root will always have access to the keyboard.

Comment: The command above grabs the keyboard within X without root privilege. So it is trivial to install a keylogger to an ubuntu desktop. The question is how to avoid this.

Answer (score -4):

As others said here, it's not possible to protect only a program like gnome-terminal or other terminal from key logging, only if you restrict standard users to execute any key logger or if you stop/pause any key logger process.

Next I will show you how you can do these in case of `xinput` command, but the same methods can be used for any other key logger. If a key logger uses `xinput` command, it is not necessary to apply the method upon it as long as you apply it upon `xinput`.

#### 1. Restrict standard users to use `xinput` command

You can [restrict standard users to use `xinput` command](https://askubuntu.com/q/247452/147044) using the following command:

```
sudo chmod go-x /usr/bin/xinput
```

#### 2. Restrict standard users to use `xinput` command with `test-xi2` argument

You can [restrict standard users to use `xinput` command with `test-xi2` argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92049/37944) by writing a wrapper for this command. To do this, go in terminal and follow the instructions below:

- Get root privileges:

  ```
  sudo -i
  ```
- Move `xinput` file in another directory which is not in any user's PATH (for example `/opt`):

  ```
  mv /usr/bin/xinput /new/path/to/xinput
  ```
- Create your wrapper for `xinput` command in `/usr/bin`:

  ```
  gedit /usr/bin/xinput
  ```

  Add the following script inside:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  if [ "$@" != "${@/test-xi2/}" -a "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
      echo "`basename $0` $@: Permission denied"
  else
      /new/path/to/xinput $@
  fi
  ```

  Save the file and close it.
- Make the new wrapper executable:

  ```
  chmod +x /usr/bin/xinput
  ```

While first method is safety, using second method, the user may still circumvent it by calling the original `xinput` directly if he know its new location.

#### 3. Stop/pause any `xinput` process

You can stop or pause any `xinput` process before to enter a password or anything else that you don't want to be logged. To do this, add the following bash function at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
processof () {
    xinput_pids=" $(pidof $1) "
    if [ "$xinput_pids" = "  " ]; then
        echo "Nothing to stop/pause/continue. $1: no such process!"
        return
    fi
    for pid in $xinput_pids; do
        case $2 in
        "stop") 
            kill $pid
            echo "$1: stopped"
            ;;
        "pause")
            kill -stop $pid
            echo "$1: paused"   
            ;;
        "continue")
            kill -cont $pid
            echo "$1: continue"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "$1 is runnig"
            ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

Now, after you reopen your terminal, anytime you want, using this function you can:

- stop/kill all `xinput` processes:

  ```
  processof xinput stop
  ```
- pause all `xinput` processes:

  ```
  processof xinput pause
  ```
- resume all `xinput` processes:

  ```
  processof xinput continue
  ```

In fact, with this function you can stop/pause any process do you wish before to do something (such as entering the password):

```
processof [process_name] [stop|pause|continue]
```

If you don't know how to detect how to detect an active keylogger on your system, see:

- **[How can I detect a keylogger on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169887/how-can-i-detect-a-keylogger-on-my-system)**

These methods maybe are not the best solutions, but I hope to give you an idea about what you can do...

Comment: xinput is just an example of a keylogger. The question is about protecting input from every possible keylogger.

Comment: @yanychar This was just an example about how you can restrict the access to `xinput`. In the same manner you can restrict the access to everything else thing that make you think that is a keylogger. If you are the administrator of the system, nothing can stop you doing this. In fact you should know everything that moves in your system.

Comment: Any program can connect to the X server through sockets and keylog, it's not even required that the key logger uses an external program.

Comment: @RamchandraApte So, where is the problem?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu your solution is ineffective and useless. `xinput` isn't even SUID (-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 48504 Aug 15 2012 /usr/bin/xinput)

Comment: @RamchandraApte What make you think this?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Because you don't need xinput to keylog. (it doesn't need an external command nor does the malicious program need to be SUID) your solution will simply allow one to control the execution of xinput

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10736/discussion-between-ramchandra-apte-and-radu-rdeanu)

Comment: @RamchandraApte You didn't read with attention the answer. These methods have been given as examples for `xinput`. But any process can be used instead. Or what do you want to said: that there are hidden processes which can not be found?

Comment: The most basic example to prove it ineffective: Copy a stock version of (ubuntu) xinput from a usb stick, download it from web or e-mail it to yourself and run it in your home folder. Same effect as using the unrestricted /usr/bin/xinput.