# Black screen with keystroke history

Tags: keyboard

Sometimes when Ubuntu crashes, I get a black screen where every keystroke I made in the past session is visible. Any new keystrokes I make get displayed on the screen too.

Does Ubuntu store the keystrokes in memory for a longer period than required? Where? If so, can this be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

A black screen with EVERY keystroke? Both shell and X? Are you sure you are not seeing bash history ([How to clear bash history completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191999/how-to-clear-bash-history-completely))? Wish you had made a photo, you could be referring to smth else than logged keystrokes.

Ubuntu doesn't log keystrokes, at least if you have a stock distribution which hadn't been tampered with. It may be possible that you had a keylogger accidentally installed on your machine. You can check here for reference: [How can I detect a keylogger on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169887/how-can-i-detect-a-keylogger-on-my-system), but in your place I'd first try to establish what exactly you are seeing on the screen.

Comment: Not just shell; I'm sure it wasn't bash history. This has happened multiple times on multiple clean installations. I suspect it to be some part of the device driver/etc, but not sure.