# How to make a key stroke recorder (for non-malicious purposes)?

Tags: gnome, bash, scripts, keyboard, log

When you first look at this question and its title you are going to assume that I want this for malicious purposes, however that is not the case, it is because I type a lot of things, and sometimes (rather often actually) I just want to check what I did, say, half an hour ago, or make sure that I didn't just make a big mistake, however there is no real history of what I type so this becomes rather difficult. 
Another reason for this might be that my computer is running certain tasks which should not be interrupted until complete, so I can't suspend my machine, but I would like to be able to come back and tell if anybody typed anything (because most often this is a CLI only session so I don't need to worry about the mouse and I can use other software such as screen recording for that), or executed any keyboard shortcuts.

**So, long story short**, I would like a "keylogger" however I do not want to install one from anywhere as I don't trust that there aren't any backdoors or anything, so what I would like is a script ([and I know that this sort of thing is possible](https://askubuntu.com/a/169931/364819)) which:

- Is able to record (probably in a text file) keystrokes and also when the pressing of a key once results in the character coming out more than once
- Is able to tell apart keyboard shortcuts from normal typing and also show what the result of the keyboard shortcut was
- Works in the GUI and CLI
- Works on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 (my system)
- Preferably written in a language such as bash
- Only keeps a log of the last 5 minutes (though this should be a variable time which can be easily changed in the code)

Comment: There is one in the repositories. You do not trust our repositories? Then the world is doomed. I would not trust software that "which can be easily changed in the code)" .... that should be in a configfile (insert angry face)

Comment: Oh and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/logkeys.8.html has a hint: " It relies on
       the   event  interface  of  Linux  input  subsystem  (normally  devices
       **/dev/input/eventX**)."

Comment: @Rinzwind: The `universe` repository is not really checked in-terms of security stuff by the Ubuntu Security Team so I don't really trust it so much, especially with this kind of thing...

Comment: But... you could download the source and peak in that without installing it. Oh and I believe logkeys has no backdoors. I've seen the code a year or so ago since I was curious too ;-)

Comment: Really, your nickname seems to be great for you! You can read the [source code](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys) and then compile. Also check the readme for assembly backdoor code. 

Comment: Maybe you can partially use this: http://www.r00tsec.com/2012/11/key-logger-with-bash-script.html