# When restating I briefly see a black window with all of the text I have typed

Tags: 18.04

Does anyone know what this is?  It makes me fear that there is a key logger on my system.  I am using Ubuntu 18.4 and it is fully up to date.  It seems like a security concern because I have been able to read my passwords in plain text there briefly.

Comment: This sounds SUPER sketchy!!!!! Did you see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/169887/how-can-i-detect-a-keylogger-on-my-system ????