# How to restrict a user from accessing a particular application?

Tags: guest-session, restricted-access

I want to restrict an application being opened under ordinary privileges. Only root shall run the application, so that contents wont be seen by others and they wont change anything.

Comment: @VRU I am not sure your link is a duplicate.

Comment: @VRU Since you can't dupe acros sites, we can definitely use a Q&A on this (unless we declare this off-topic, which I wouldn't).

Comment: @GKUTTY for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527876/how-to-restrict-a-linux-user-to-be-only-able-to-read-home-user-and-nothing-else

Answer (score 2):

There should be a better way to do this (maybe with AppArmor?) but you can always change the permissions of the executable. Suppose you want to disable access to `nano`. Their default permissions are as follows:

```
 ➜  ls -la /bin/nano
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 192008 Oct  1 15:12 /bin/nano
```

It can be executed by owner, group and others. To maintain only owner execution you can use

```
sudo chmod g-x /bin/nano
sudo chmod o-x /bin/nano
```

After this, if you execute it in a terminal as an ordinary user:

```
 ➜  nano
bash: /usr/bin/nano: Permission denied
```

Please note that this is not a bullet-proof solution. If the application you want to lock has other entry points they could still be accessed. For example, if you tried the same trick with Firefox:

```
 ➜  ls -la /usr/bin/firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jan 17 08:26 /usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

Even if you limited access to `/usr/bin/firefox`, as it is just a link to `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh` it could be still be executed by there (or using `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`, which is used in the .sh file).